# Sum of the elements in a discrete set

Tags: sequences-and-series, set-theory

(This may have been asked elsewhere but I cannot find it.)

Take the set of positive integers $\{1,2,...\frac{n}{2} (n+1)\}$ and put them into $n$ subsets as follows:

$S_{1}=\{1\}$
$S_{2}=\{2,3\}$
$S_{3}=\{4,5,6\}$

And so on so that $S_{n}$ contains exactly $n$ elements.

What is the sum of the elements of $S_{n}$ in terms of $n$?

Comment: Sum of $S_k$ will be $\dfrac{k(k^2 + 1)}{2}$

Comment: Thanks @TonyPizza, I had something similar in mind but couldn't work out a neat way of showing it. Did you sum all the sets and then subtract the sum of all but set "n" to get this? (That was what I was doing but wonder if there is a "nicer" approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $Z_k := 1+2+\ldots+k = \dfrac{k(k+1)}{2}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Notice that the largest element of $S_n$ is $Z_n$. So the sum of elements of $S_n$ is
\begin{align}
Z_{Z_n} - Z_{Z_{n-1}} 
&= \dfrac{Z_{n}(Z_{n}+1)}{2} - \dfrac{Z_{n-1}(Z_{n-1}+1)}{2}\\
&= \dfrac{(Z_{n-1}+n)(Z_{n-1}+n+1)}{2} - \dfrac{Z_{n-1}(Z_{n-1}+1)}{2}
\end{align}
which simplifies to $\dfrac{n(n^2+1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Commenter TonyPizza suggested $\frac{n(n^{2}+1)}{2}$ as a solution and as far as I can tell it works perfectly.

My approach to the problem was to sum all the elements in all of the sets, so find the sum of the series $1+2+...+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and then subtract the sum of the elements of $S_{1}$ to $S_{n-1}$.

This approach seems to work but I also feel is excessive and a different approach might be possible.

Any ideas are welcome.